# How to change table with innodb/myisam engine to federated

Tags: mysql

In my.ini I added

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

When I type in a shell `show engines;` I get this result:
[image]

But when I try to change one of this tables which are on innodb engine to federated I get an error. When I try to create/alter table with sqlyog there is no federated engine

[image]

Can anyone help me? And if I change innodb/myisam table with data to federated table, will I lose any data? I dont use transactions in table

Comment: No offense in asking this, but do you actually know what the federated engine is? I recommend you read the MySQL manual about it. You don't convert a table to federated, you just create it.

Comment: @tombom Have 2 mysql databases on different hosts, want trigger after insert data to one database it inserted to another . I'm new in mysql , in sql server I can create linked server and do it . But how to do in mysql ? Both databases have similar table. Both tables are in innodb engine and I dont want to lose any data , that why I try change engine to ferderated

Comment: Do you want to do this for all tables in a database? If yes, what you actually want is called replication.

Comment: @tombom I know about replication, but I want it only on one table not more, any advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html):

> First, you must have a table on the remote server that you want to
>   access by using a FEDERATED table. Suppose that the remote table is in
>   the federated database and is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> The example uses a MyISAM table, but the table could use any storage
>   engine.
>
> Next, create a FEDERATED table on the local server for accessing the
>   remote table:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

> (Before MySQL 5.0.13, use COMMENT rather than CONNECTION.)
>
> The basic structure of this table should match that of the remote
>   table, except that the ENGINE table option should be FEDERATED and the
>   CONNECTION table option is a connection string that indicates to the
>   FEDERATED engine how to connect to the remote server.

Comment: @GeoVIP No, you can't. The concept behind `federated` is still not clear, isn't it? The federated engine is like a link to another table. You select something from the local federated table, the data comes from the remote whatever-engine-table. You can't use triggers to write data to a remote server.

Comment: I have answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503342/how-to-create-trigger-for-insert-data-to-another-database/26504320#26504320

It will not work ?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's actually a fancy trick. But you have to create the table the other way round than I described in my answer. The federated table on the localhost, and the real table on the remote host, where you want to write data to. Nice.

Comment: I haven't used the federated engine much, cause from my experience it's painfully slow. But maybe just for my use case.

Comment: why slow ? federated engine not support index ?

Comment: Don't think so, haven't investigated it much. For writing it may not be so serious.

Comment: Gave a +1 to both question and answer because I learnt something today - it's a kind of master-master (or bidirectional) replication when you only might want to do it for an important table (or subset of tables).

Comment: @tombom the federated storage engine absolutely *does* support indexes, and in fact, they're critical for good performance... but they work in a very unconventional way.  If `FEDERATED` doesn't know about a useful index for a given query, it won't send a `WHERE` clause in the remote query, and it will fetch the entire table and scan it locally.  It usually makes sense to declare indexes on the federated table that don't even exist on the real table, so that it won't do this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Interesting, thanks for your comment.